# "core:schema:warn Unknown property `475` for component/system `text`. +1ms" in Aframe

Tags: aframe

My text reads like below,
    avaTxt = "abc; def\n";

The semicolon is resulting in multiple error messages like above error message.

Does anybody know the possible reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the text component ? 
If so, You can't add a semicolon text value like this:

```
<a-entity position="1 0 0" text="value:abc; def\n;color:#000"></a-entity>
```

because the semicolon separates the attributes. Doing it this way You try to push 'def\n' into the component, which does not have a corresponding attribute, and You get the errors which You describred.

---

When You use the text, as a defined primitive, You can make Your value as You initially wanted:

```
<a-text position="0 1 0" value="abc; def\n" color="#000"></a-text>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/7L3npkzo/).